# Is there a way to pass multiple base packages in annotation @EnableFeignClient

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-feign

I'm currently using spring-cloud-starter-openfeign with 1.4.4.RELEASE version.

I have annotated my main class with @EnableFeignClients and I have feign clients in multiple packages due to the structuring of the project.

So I tried adding basepackages attribute with multiple packages and I'm getting compile time error.

```
@EnableFeignClients(basePackages = {"com.abc.proj.services.api.client", "com.abc.pro.console.feign"})
```

**Getting below error:**

**',' unexpected**

Comment: Can you post the full exception stack trace or compiler error? There is nothing wrong with your `@EnableFeignClients`.

Comment: Got below error when I started my application.
 `unexpected token: com.company.project.services.api.client @ line 27, column 37.
   @EnableFeignClients(basePackages = {"com.company.project.services.api.client", "com.company.project.services.console.feign"})`

Comment: Post the `com.company.project.services.api.client` class that caused the problem, the definition with annotations is enough.